# converting resultset from OleDbDataReader into list

Tags: c#, .net, oledbdatareader

Consider a Winforms app connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database and running a SQL `SELECT` statement:

```
string myConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=qcvaluestest;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

string mySelectQuery = "SELECT top 500 name, finalconc from qvalues where rowid between 0 and 25000;";

OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

myCommand.Connection.Open();

OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

How can you read the results of the query into a list?

Comment: what type of list? since your returning two values from your query are looking for like an array or like a list of objects, or a list box?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: As an aside, look into the `using` statement. You have some resources that implement `IDisposable`, you want to ensure those resources are properly disposed of. Best practice is to wrap such resources in `using` statements that will automatically dispose of them for you. (Your disposable resources are the `OleDb*` classes.)

Comment: @anthony thank you very much for this. can you please show me an example of what you mean

Comment: @i am, actually, AJ's answer shows the `using` statement. Suffice it to say, if you have an object that implements `IDisposable`, best practice is to wrap the declaration and usage of it as such: `using (DisposableObject myObject = new DisposableObject) { \\* code that uses the object here *\ }`. The scope of the object will be limited to inside the brackets below, and the compiler will expand the code into try/finally blocks that will call `Dispose` on the object for you so that it can clean up after itself.

Comment: @anthony how do i know which objects implement idisposable?

Comment: @i am, good question! Visual Studio doesn't naturally highlight them, after all. Check their implementation (do they have a `Dispose` method?), the documentation, etc. Rule of thumb, data access objects (`Sql*`, `OleDb*`, `Odbc*`) typically implement IDisposable. As do `Stream*` objects from the `System.IO` namespace. But ultimately, you just need to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have defined a class that is something like

```
class MyData
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int FinalConc {get; set;} // or whatever the type should be
}
```

You would iterate through the results of your query to load a list.

```
List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.Name = (string)myReader["name"];
    data.FinalConc = (int)myReader["finalconc"]; // or whatever the type should be
    list.Add(data);
}

// work with the list
```

If you just need one of the given fields, you can forego the class definition and simply have a `List<T>`, where `T` is the type of whatever field you want to hold.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something as (adapt it for your convenience):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

List<Person> dbItems = new List<Person>();

while(myReader.Read())
{
   Person objPerson = new Person();

   objPerson.Name = Convert.ToString(myReader["Name"]);
   objPerson.Age = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["Age"]);

   dbItems.Add(objPerson);
}
```

Comment: This is going to turn each row into multiple items in the list. So given two columns, the first row would be dbItems[0] and dbItems[1], the second row would be dbItems[2] and dbItems[3], etc. Is this intuitive? What if the types of the columns are not the same?

Comment: @pycoder, this is good but not exactly correct, it just creates a 1 dimensional array with the first element columnname1 then the second columnname2 then the third column1, then 2, then 1...etc but i need (1, 2), (1, 2), (1,2). ....

Comment: The real code is something as Anthony Pegram had written in his post. Build first a class that map column one to one and then build a List of that class e memorize data in it.

Comment: @i am girl: warning about NULL fields in your query results and catch conversion exception :)

Answer (score 1):

List of what?  Do you have a class setup that has properties for `name` and `finalconc`?  Saying you do, and it looks like this:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //not sure what finalconc type would be, so here just using string
    public string FinalConc { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would do something like this:

```
var queryResults = new List<QueryResult>();
using(var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        queryResults.Add(new QueryResult
            { 
                Name = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("name")), 
                FinalConc = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("finalconc"))
            });
    }
}
```