# Load database to list in c#

Tags: c#, database, orm

I am quering a database and am wondering if there is a way to load the results back into a list. The only way i curerntly know of how to get info from a database is within a datatable. I can always get it into a datatable and then loop through the rows in the datatable and add them to a list. But is there a way to directly get the result of a query into a list? This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, GRADE, PHONE from database WHERE PHONE=123456", conn);
conn.Open();
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
conn.Close();
```

The result should be a list entry of the form (id, grade, phone):

61265,95,123456

Thanks

Comment: What if the query returns more than 1 row?

Comment: AFIK, you need to call the `Add()` method of list to add each element.

Comment: It will only return one row. Thats a requirement

Comment: why do you need a list if it returns one row? am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider you have a class

```
public ListData()
{
  public int Id{get;set;} //Assuming DB field is int
  public string Grade{get;set;}  //Assuming DB field is a string
  public string PhoneNo{get;set;} //Assuming DB field is a string
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
list<ListData> theList =(from item in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         Select new ListData()
                              {
                                 Id= (int)item["ID"],
                                 Grade = (string)item["GRADE"],
                                 PhoneNo = (string)item["PHONE"]
                              }
                        ).ToList()
```

**Note:**

*1.  I just type it on the comment textbox so there might be some errors if you just copy-paste the code*

*2.  You also need to handle null values if any on GRADE / PHONE*

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089628/converting-resultset-from-oledbdatareader-into-list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Adapter, e.g.

```
DataSet mSet = new DataSet();
OleDbTableAdapter mAdapter = new OleDbTableAdapter(myOleDbCommand); 
mAdapter.Fill(mSet); 
myOleDbCommand.Connection.Close();
```